# Categorizing images using Exiftool

Tags: exiftool, tagging

I would like to categorize images in my photo collection with tags describing the image. for example, if the image contains a dog, a cat and a baby, and is taken in a kitchen, the list of tags should be `cat,dog,baby,kitchen`

I don't see which tag that should be stored in. I was considering using `EXIF:ImageDescription` from the [EXIF](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html) tag list in the documentation. (e.g. `exiftool -EXIF:ImageDescription=baby,cat,dog,kitchen *`) But I guess that is not the most optimal way to do it. is there a smarter tag to use?

(Next evolution would be to do some indexing to be able to easier find tagged images on my server)

Comment: The [IPTC Photo Metadata Standard](https://www.iptc.org/std/photometadata/specification/IPTC-PhotoMetadata) is a good place to look to see where you might want to place data.  Alternatively, you could use a image management program such as Adobe Bridge or Digikam (both free) which will make it easier to put metadata in the correct places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my workflow (use Lightroom) I see keywords are stored in IPTC IIM variable `Keywords`. Also you can check for variable `Subject` (Lightroom store the keywords also there).

`Image Description` is used mostly for the name of particular image.